# AzCopy round-tripping files which are URL encoded due to unrepresentable characters in Windows file system

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azcopy

I've been using AzCopy to copy files to and from blob storage. As discussed on the [AzCopy blob page(s)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2012/12/03/azcopy-uploading-downloading-files-for-windows-azure-blobs.aspx), if a blob file has a character which cannot be represented in the windows file system (in my case the :), it will be replaced by one of the rules defined (“.” => “dot”; “..” => “dotdot”; “/” => “slash” - as per that page), or with the url encoded percent value (as is the case for : -> %3A).

For my use case, I have a set of blobs, for which I do some post processing, and then upload a set of identical "response file" blobs into a different container. This works fine, but has the issue that when I upload those blobs from disk, the url encoded file name isn't unescaped back to the original blob name, so my blobs all have names with %'s everywhere.

I don't think AzCopy supports this right now, but thought I'd ask. I may just go through and rename all of my blobs to be consistent on both sides.

Answer (score 0):

When AzCopy is uploading files from your local disk to blobs, it cannot decide whether the file name actually contains the percent sign or it was encoded from an unsupported character, because such operations are not tracked across AzCopy runs.

Answer (score 0):

I believe AzCopy 10.3 will round-trip the names correctly.